# Видимость переменной в анонимных функциях

Tags: java

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой, из метода run() не видно переменную countAnimationDisplayName.

Сам код:

```
tasks.put(player.getName(), new BukkitRunnable() {
        int countAnimationDisplayName = 0;

        public void run() {
            WrapperPlayServerScoreboardObjective objective = new WrapperPlayServerScoreboardObjective();
            objective.setDisplayName(board.animationDisplayName.get(countAnimationDisplayName));
            //objective.

            countAnimationDisplayName += 1;
        }
    }.runTaskTimer(this, 1L, intervalUpdate * 20L).getTaskId());
```

Ошибка из IDE: countAnimationDisplayName cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: а сам javac видит?

Comment: переменная должна быть видна, ошибка явно в чем то другом, но без исходников трудно сказать.